# I need to override npm install, I think. Any suggestions how?

Tags: npm, pnpm

I have a npm 7 monorepo which I have migrated to use pnpm but one of the build tools I have runs `npm i` which cannot be changed.

I tried this

```
"install": "pnpm install":
```

in the hope that it would reroute to `pnpm`, but it still does a regular npm install. I changed the command to:

```
"install": "echo foo"
```

and discovered that it installs first, then echos out.

I have written a script loosely based on `pnpm`s recommendation of `npx only-allow pnpm` but I still cannot stop `npm` from installing natively.

Lastly, I have tried a `postinstall` to wipe the `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`, and then do `pnpm install`, which works but is horrific.

```
"postinstall": "rm -rf node_modules && rm package-lock.json && pnpm install",
```

EDIT: the last hack doesn't work because `pnpm` also runs `postinstall`

Any pro tips?